# Must the perp. bisectors of opposite sides in a quadrilateral intersect inside it, if one of the angles is right and an adjacent angle is obtuse?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

This is given that the lines aren't parallel so that the perpendicular bisectors will intersect at some point.

I've been trying to find a counterexample for this, but I can't, so I'm assuming that this statement is true, but I couldn't find any other information on the subject.

If it's true, how would I prove it?

EDIT: One of the angles is right and an adjacent angle is obtuse. This means the right angle and the obtuse angle are not opposite.

Comment: The statement is false. Cut a regular hexagon along a diagonal to get two trapezium. the perpendicular bisectors of the two slant sides of a trapezium intersect at the midpoint of the longest edge. Now squeeze the trapezisum in a direction perpendicular to the two parallel sides, you will move the point of intersection outside the trapezium.

Comment: @achille hui I forgot to mention that one of the angles in the quadrilateral is a right angle.

Comment: Make a trapezium in such a way that one of the non-parallel sides is perpendicular to two opposite parallel sides. The perpendicular bisectors never meet.

Answer (score 1):

No, the statement is false. Construct any right trapezium, which is not a rectangle. The perpendicular bisectors of the 2 non-parallel sides will meet at the midpoint of the longer side. This can be proved fairly easily.

Can you try and prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Angle at B is $90^{\circ}.$ The shown perpendicular lines in the construction do not meet inside the quadrilateral, so the proposition is false.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a counterexample; to show that it's false you need at least 1 example where it fails; for truth, you need to show a general statement where it holds:

Create two acute angles adjacent to that right angle; extend lines from those acute angles to close the quadrilateral. Draw perpendicular bisectors on either pair of sides; they will not intersect.

Try it. It's not rigorous at all, I know, but it works. On either side the perpendicular bisector away from the right angle will be deflected into the acute side.